# Careers Profile gone missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I'm trying to access my profile at Careers but it's a little confusing. I can't find it anywhere and what looks like the new name for it "Developer Story" errors out when I click on it. Can anyone help?

Comment: We're investigating.

Answer (score 1):

The Careers CV is no longer available, as it has been replaced with the Developer Story. Your story was throwing an error which should now be resolved and you should be able to access it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current).